# Function type with a receiver

Tags: go, type-alias

How can I declare a function with a receiver as a type?

I thought I would be able to the following, but it complains about syntax error:

```
type myFunc func(s *State) (blah Blah) err

func main() {
    b := &Blah{}
    s := &State{}

    var f = myF
    s.f(b)
}

func (s *State) myF(blah Blah) err {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Don't think you can do that.

Comment: Use an interface.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can define a function type that takes the receiver as its first argument (that's essentially what methods are).

```
type myFunc func(*State, Blah) error
```

You can then use a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions) to create a value of that type:

```
type Blah struct{}
type State struct{}

func (s *State) myF(Blah) error { return nil }

var f myFunc = (*State).myF
```

> If M is in the method set of type T, T.M is a function that is callable as a regular function with the same arguments as M prefixed by an additional argument that is the receiver of the method.
>
> [...]
>
> The expression
>
> ```
> T.Mv
> ```
>
> yields a function equivalent to Mv but with an explicit receiver as its first argument; it has signature
>
> ```
> func(tv T, a int) int
> ```